# Make RespondJS Ignore an eternally hosted CSS file (Font Awesome)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, media-queries, font-awesome

So I got RespondJS working with my CDN and stylesheets with the following code:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
      <link href='https://d1unzhqf5a606m.cloudfront.net/respond-proxy.html' id='respond-proxy' rel='respond-proxy'>
      <link href='/respondjs/respond.proxy.gif' id='respond-redirect' rel='respond-redirect'>
      <script src='/respondjs/respond.proxy.js'></script>
    <![endif]-->
```

However, it's error on a permission denied when it tries to grab FontAwesome from the CDN I'm using:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is there a way to get RespondJS to ignore this stylesheet so I stop getting the errors? I'd really rather not put that CSS on my CDN.

You can see it in the wild on our site, [Alarm Grid](https://www.alarmgrid.com).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: Thanks, but it's not a CORS issue. It's specifically related to RespondJS's proxy script.

Comment: I get no font awesome on either Firefox or Chrome latest Mac OS and Google Dev tools indicates that it's because Access Control Allow Origin ... How can an IE conditional commented script block on non IE? It doesn't

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help, but the issue is not with Font Awesome icons. I actually only use them on one page: https://www.alarmgrid.com/affirm